# Google ML Service Specific Terms Inquiry

Tags: terms-of-service

I would like to get clarification on the use of Google’s Machine Learning Services according to its [Service Specific Terms (section 12)](https://cloud.google.com/terms/service-terms). I am working on an IVR solution that transcribes audio using Google Speech to Text API and synthesizes audio back using Google Text to Speech API.

Would an IVR application considered an embedded device such as cars, TVs, appliances, or speakers​ (not allowed)? or alternatively, it would be considered a personal computing device: smartphones, tablets, laptops, and desktops (allowed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We contacted Google legal department and they have confirmed that an IVR would not be considered an embedded device hence the use is allowed.